Может ли пользователь добавить бота на discord сервер
Я делаю бота и сайт для него. И хочу чтоб был список всех серверов где бота нет, но пользователь имеет права чтобы его добавить.
С эндпоинта https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds и получаю список серверов. И у каждого есть permissions и permissions_new. Надо ли что-то проверять по этим значениям или это вообще делается по-другому. Может есть какой-то калькулятор прав (не бота, а пользователя)
